# Unity 3d pass bool variable between two objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

how i can pass a simple boolean variable between two different object? 
I can try this but didn't work...

*First script:*

```
  public class CollisionController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public PlayerMovement movement;
    public bool active = false;



    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if(collision.collider.tag == "Obstacle")
        {
            active = true;
        }
    }
}
```

*Second script (that read the boolean variable "active")*

```
   public class EmptyControllerColl : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CollisionController controller;
    public PlayerMovement movement;

    public bool activeLocal = false;

    private void Start()
    {
        GetComponentInChildren<CollisionController>();
    }
    void Update()
    {


        activeLocal = controller.active;

        if(activeLocal == false)
        {
            Debug.Log("Nothing...");
        }

        if(activeLocal == true)
        {
            Debug.Log("Game over");

        }
    }
}
```

When the variable bool "Active" change its status, the variable "activeLocal" don't change status.. How can I resolve this problem?

Collision Controller is "connect" to Cube Object.

EmptyControllerColl is "connect" to emptyGameObject (parent of Cube).

Comment: what is `_ = GameObject.Find("cubo Variant").GetComponent<CollisionController>().active;` supposed to do?

Comment: If you want to access a component attached to a child of you you can simply use `GetComponentInChildren<CollisionController>()`, however you shouldn't do this in `Update` at all ... rather store it in your `controller` field. Then there is not really a need to additionally store this `bool` value also locally ...

Comment: @derHugo "_ = GameObject.Find("cubo Variant")" it's a hint of Visual Studio.. however I put in Update because i need rapid "refresh" to the status of the bool variable..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
_ = GameObject.Find("cubo Variant").GetComponent<CollisionController>().active;
```

makes no sense. First of all there is no field or variable declared with the name `_` so this shouldn't even compile at all. And secondly what do you need this for? Rather store the according reference **once** in the `controller` field and reuse it later.

Then for your usecase there is no need at all to store the value in a local variable ... this makes things only more complicated. Simply where you need it get the value from `controller.active`.

Also do not use `==` for tags. Rather check via [`CompareTag`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.CompareTag.html). The problem is that `==` silently fails if you have any typo or the tag doesn't exist at all. `CompareTag` rather throws an error that the given tag is not valid.

```
public class EmptyControllerColl : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Best already drag this in via the Inspector in Unity
    [SerializeField] private CollisionController controller;
    public PlayerMovement movement;

    // As fallback get it ONCE on runtime
    private void Awake()
    {
        // since you say the cube is a child of this empty object you do not use
        // Find at all but can simply use GetComponentInChildren
        if(!controller) controller = GetComponentInChildren<CollisionController>(true);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // No need to store this in a local field at all
        if(!controller.active)
        {
            Debug.Log("Nothing...");
        }
        // use if else since both cases are exclusive and you don't even need to check the value twice
        else 
        {
            Debug.Log("Game over");
        }
    }
}
```

---

#### Event Driven - part A

In general you should avoid poll checks for a bool value in `Update` and rather come up with a more event driven solution! An example could look like:

```
public class CollisionController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public PlayerMovement movement;

    // Here everyone who wants can add listeners that get called as soon as
    // we invoke this event. We will do it everytime the 'active' value is changed
    public event Action<bool> OnActiveStateChanged;

    // Backing field for 'active'
    private bool _active;

    // Property that reads and writes '_active'
    // Everytime it is assigned it also invokes 'OnActiveStateChanged'
    private bool active
    {
        get { return _active; }
        set
        {
            _active = value;
            OnActiveStateChanged?.Invoke(_active);
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if(collision.collider.CompareTag("Obstacle"))
        {
            active = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you would register a listener for this event like

```
public class EmptyControllerColl : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Best already drag this in via the Inspector in Unity
    [SerializeField] private CollisionController controller;
    public PlayerMovement movement;

    // As fallback get it ONCE on runtime
    private void Awake()
    {
        // since you say the cube is a child of this empty object you do not use
        // Find at all but can simply use GetComponentInChildren
        if(!controller) controller = GetComponentInChildren<CollisionController>(true);

        // register a callback. It is allowed an save to unregister first
        // which makes sure this is only registered exactly once
        controller.OnActiveStateChanged -= HandleControlerActiveStateChanged;
        controller.OnActiveStateChanged += HandleControlerActiveStateChanged;
    }

    private void HandleGameOver()
    {
        Debug.Log("Game over");
    }

    private void HandleControlerActiveStateChanged(bool value)
    {
        if(!value)
        {
            Debug.Log("Nothing...");
        }
        else 
        {
            Debug.Log("Game over");
        }
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
         // always clean up listeners
         controller.OnActiveStateChanged -= HandleControlerActiveStateChanged;
    }
}
```

This now is way more efficient since you don't all time run an `Update` method. Instead the `HandleControlerActiveStateChanged` is only called when the value of `active` is actually changed.

---

#### Event Driven - part B

And then actually in your case there is need to use a `bool` **at all** you could use a simple `event Action` instead and remove all the `bools` entirely:

```
public class CollisionController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public PlayerMovement movement;

    public event Action OnGameOver;

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if(collision.collider.CompareTag("Obstacle"))
        {
            OnGameOver?.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

Now you would register a listener for this event like

```
public class EmptyControllerColl : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private CollisionController controller;
    public PlayerMovement movement;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if(!controller) controller = GetComponentInChildren<CollisionController>(true);

        controller.OnGameOver -= HandleGameOver;
        controller.OnGameOver += HandleGameOver;
    }

    private void HandleGameOver()
    {
        Debug.Log("Game over");
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        controller.OnGameOver -= HandleGameOver;
    }
}
```

Comment: I need that the variable "active" (first script) send its status to "activeLocal" (Second script) but when the bool "active" becomes "true" , it doesn't send its status to "activeLocal"..

Comment: what for? Did you read the answer? You don't need to store it in a local field at all .. simply use `controller.active`

Comment: Yes, I have read the answer, but doesn't work... On console i read only "Nothing" even when the "active" bool becomes "true"...

Comment: @upstagesum Well you can't set it via the `Inspector` .. it has to be set via your trigger enter .. and make sure you set `active` .. not `_active`. If you only see the `Nothing` then the `active` was set to `false` ... Do you have multiple instances of this object?

Comment: Thanks.. In the "Event driven -Part A" in this line "public event Action<bool> OnActiveStateChanged;" I have this error when i try to run the project "Assets\Scripts\CollisionController.cs(10,18): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Action<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
" . sorry for the time I'm wasting you.. :(

Comment: you need a `using System;` at the top of your file

Answer (score -1):

```
using UnityEngine;

public class CollisionController : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        // Calls the function ApplyDamage with a value of 5
        // Every script attached to the game object
        // that has an ApplyDamage function will be called.
        gameObject.SendMessage("ApplyDamage", 5.0);
    }
}

public class EmptyControllerColl : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void ApplyDamage(float damage)
    {
        print(damage);
    }
}
```

> https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SendMessage.html